# How to get uploaded file served in url nestjs

Tags: node.js, angular, nestjs

Hy guys need a little help,
How to get the uploaded file served in nestjs
I am uploading images in /uploads folder the images are being stored but how to viee those images in client side.
If i am not wrong so we have to serve the static content but i am not able to get it working any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please post your code so we can tell which part you did wrong

Comment: You could serve those files using https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/serve-static

Comment: Thanks for response, i did solved it by serving the content